# Appropriate hypothesis contrast between 4 different car brands (fuel consumption)

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, anova

*Is there any significant difference between the manufacturers regarding fuel consumption?* I typically use `t.test` as:

```
> t.test( cons$A, cons$B, 
>         alternative = "two.sided", 
>         paired = FALSE, 
>         var.equal = TRUE )
```

cons is (e.g):

```
  A   B    C   D
 9.3 9.1  9.8 8.6
 8.9 8.3 10.4 8.9
 8.7 8.2  9.2 8.1
 9.1 9.0  9.7 7.8
 8.6 9.1 10.4 9.1
```

t.test is that is valid for only two independent variables.

Comment: I think this is more of a stats.stackexchange question, but you're looking for ANOVA

Comment: Perhaps you could do a one-way ANOVA (four levels of the factor). Then if the F-statistic shows some differences among level population means, you can use some ad-hoc method of comparisons (such as Tukey HSD) to control the 'family error rate' involved in making ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ paired comparisons. // Crucial parts of this are sufficiently simple that you could use a calculator and tabled values for distributions. // If you don''t know how to do this in R, there are lots of help sites illustrating that. To make sure you're on the right track, I will show some Minitab output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted first data frame in this one:

```
Brands  Consumption
A       9.3
A       8.9
A       8.7
A       9.1
A       8.6
B       9.1
B       8.3
B       8.2
B       9
B       9.1
B       8.3
..      ..
..      ..
```

Then I applied:

```
>anl<- aov(Consumption~Brands)
>summary(anl)
>TukeyHSD(anl, conf.level = 0.99)
```

I got the same results as you but represented differently. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Data summaries:

```
Descriptive Statistics: A, B, C, D 

Variable  N   Mean  SE Mean  StDev  Minimum     Q1  Median      Q3   Maximum
A         5  8.920    0.128  0.286    8.600  8.650   8.900   9.200    9.300
B         5  8.740    0.201  0.451    8.200  8.250   9.000   9.100    9.100
C         5  9.900    0.228  0.510    9.200  9.450   9.800  10.400   10.400
D         5  8.500    0.243  0.543    7.800  7.950   8.600   9.000    9.100
```

Bartlett's test detects no differences in population variances. Here is is
(somewhat abridged) output of Miniab's ANOVA procedure:

```
One-way ANOVA: A, B, C, D 

Method

Null hypothesis         All means are equal
Alternative hypothesis  At least one mean is different
Significance level      α = 0.05
Equal variances were assumed for the analysis.

Factor Information

Factor  Levels  Values
Factor       4  A, B, C, D

Analysis of Variance

Source  DF  Adj SS  Adj MS  F-Value  P-Value
Factor   3   5.665  1.8885     8.99    0.001
Error   16   3.360  0.2100
Total   19   9.026
```

The P-value for the main ANOVA test is $.001 < .05,$ so there are
some significant differences among groups.

Residuals seem consistent with normality.

Tukey comparisons may
help sort out what significant differences there may be among levels A-D.

```
Tukey Pairwise Comparisons 

Grouping Information Using the Tukey Method and 95% Confidence

Factor  N   Mean  Grouping
C       5  9.900  A
A       5  8.920    B
B       5  8.740    B
D       5  8.500    B

Means that do not share a letter are significantly different.
```

It seems that group C (which has values around 10) is significantly different from groups A, B, D (which have lower values and
cannot be distinguished from one another).